# Which algorithms are used for common floating point operations in CPUs?

Tags: floating-point, cpu, cpu-architecture

I'm writing a paper on CPU design and implementation of different mathematical operations, such as addition, multiplication, division, square roots and logarithms. The paper is also about numerical analysis. However, I seem to have reached a dead end. As a result, I have some questions

1. Is there any reading material (other papers, books) which can break down some of the operations in simpler steps?
2. I was under the impression Newton's method was used for square roots (and sometimes division), and that a Taylor series was used for logarithms. Is this false? What is used?
3. Is it different in software implemented floating point support?

I realize it might depend on the CPU architecture, so answers for a common CPU like one of the newer Intel  i7 processors (x86 architecture in general) would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Logarithms aren't implemented in hardware anymore. They have it in the x87 FPU, but not in all the modern stuff.

Comment: Interesting, I'll go search a bit then. Do you know if there are any operations that depend on taylor series?

Comment: I'd assume that hardware that does implement trig functions will use either [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) or some sort of Taylor series + argument reduction. In case, they're all expensive in terms of silicon real-estate. So they aren't being included in modern extensions like SSE.

Comment: @Mysticial: they're only expensive in silicon real-estate if you want them to be fast; you can implement CORDIC using very few transistors if speed isn't an issue =)

Comment: Even x87 FPUs usually implement transcendental functions by low level software called microcode (I designed / implemented this microcode for AMD's Athlon processor, also worked on other x86 processors). The core approximations are typically of polynomial, occasionally rational kind. Usually minimax approximations, not Taylor series. Evaluation is via Horner's scheme or Estrin's scheme, as accuracy and performance require. The "Handbook of Floating Point Arithmetic" by J.-M. Muller et. al., already mentioned by Stephen Canon below, is a good starting point that explains all relevant concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For addition, you want to learn about carry look-ahead adders (specifically the [Kogge-Stone adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kogge%E2%80%93Stone_adder)).

The design of high-performance multipliers is a rather involved subject, and probably outside the scope of what you want to consider for a school project if you aren't a grad student.

Newton's method is not typically used in hardware square root or dividers; Goldschmidt's method is sometimes used (see Peter Markstein's paper on the subject for a source; it's quite readable), as it is more suited to hardware, but variants of the schoolbook method are also frequently used (often with a radix larger than two; look into signed-digit division algorithms).

Software implementations tend to be quite different entirely.

Comment: The last time I worked on a software implementation, in the 1980's, we used mainly argument reduction and a polynomial approximation based on a series.

Comment: Are you talking about this book: http://www.amazon.com/IA-64-Elementary-Functions-Hewlett-Packard-Professional/dp/0130183482
That books looks pretty perfect, I'll see if I can find a library that has it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, I'm assuming you meant this paper: http://www.m1c4a1.wz.cz/docs/goldschmidt.pdf
That also looks good, I'll take a look!

Comment: @Janiels: Yes, Markstein's book is also good, but I was talking about the paper.  You might also want to find a copy of Jean-Michel Muller's "Handbook of Floating Point Arithmetic."

Comment: I've ordered some of those books. Meanwhile I would like some materials on integer operations, like 'add' 'mul' 'div' on x86. I'm having a hard time knowing what to search for though. Can you help me?